# Google Sheets data to WordPress user account using user id

Tags: wordpress, google-sheets

this is the scenario, I wonder if it can be done and in what way. I have searched alot and i cannot seem to find a viable solution:

- User creates an account on my Wordpress website.
- User fills in a Forminator form and sends us 28 numbers which will be stored in our Google Sheets system along with the user id, ip, time and email.
- Our engine generates immediately 9 numbers based on the input numbers which had been sent by the Forminator.
- These 9 numbers need to be delivered back to the same user.
- Every 28 numbers which the users send to us are individual and specific. And our 9 generated numbers are also specific to every set of 28 numbers we receive.
- We need to deliver 9 numbers to the right user. Numbers should preferably be shown on the same page as the forminator form after user clicks on "submit" or on a new page after clicking the submit. Maybe on the users account page or similar page.
- Preferably wordpress will save both set of numbers, the 28 input numbers and 9 generated numbers.

I appreaciate any help.

Tried to send data by a Google Sheets connector but it is not a user based submission.

Comment: Hi. Why not save the 28 numbers in the WordPress database then use [JDBC](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) to read the numbers in Google Sheets or your a third-party addon as an intermediate step between the database and sheets.